# Developer console Profile object query not executed

Tags: apex, deployment, developer-console

I have query that will execute the Profile object Query in Developer console.

My query :

```
SELECT Id,Name,UserType,objectPermissions,userPermissions from Profile
```

Error:

```
SELECT Id,Name,UserType,objectPermissions,userPermissions
```

> ERROR at Row:1:Column:25 No such column 'objectPermissions' on entity
>   'Profile'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to
>   append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your
>   WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

I need to see the data UserType,objectPermissions from Profile Object.

Please some help me,

Best Regards,
Ramesh

Comment: There are no such a fields like objectPermissions, userPermissions see http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_profile.htm

Comment: Can you please refer this link    http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_profile.htm#profileobjectpermissions_title        Please let me know

Comment: I think it's not possible just by soql you need to use apex for e.g ReadResult rr=readMetaData('Profile',profiles); where profiles is array of profilesnames. For this you should have api version 30.0 and later. see this https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_readMetadata.htm

Answer (score 3):

ObjectPermissions is a distinct object in its own right, not fields on the Profile object. You need to do a query directly on that object.

```
select SobjectType, PermissionsCreate, PermissionsDelete, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsModifyAllRecords, PermissionsRead, PermissionsViewAllRecords, 
from ObjectPermissions
```